# How can I upload multiple huge CSV files and merge them?

Tags: postgresql

I need to upload multiple huge CSV files (~8-9GB) into one table. These CSV files may have rows with the same ids and in that case, I need to overwrite existing data with non-empty data from currently uploading CSV file.
Here is an example:

CSV #1:

```
id|col1|col2|col3|col4
1 |1   |1   |    |
2 |    |1   |1   |
```

CSV #2:

```
id|col1|col2|col3|col4
2 |2   |    |2   |2
3 |2   |    |    |
4 |    |2   |    |2
```

the result should be:

```
id|col1|col2|col3|col4
1 |1   |1   |    |
2 |2   |1   |2   |2
3 |2   |    |    |
4 |    |2   |    |2
```

and CSV #3:

```
id|col1|col2|col3|col4
2 |3   |    |    |
4 |    |3   |3   |
```

the result should be:

```
id|col1|col2|col3|col4
1 |1   |1   |    |
2 |3   |1   |2   |2
3 |2   |    |    |
4 |    |3   |3   |2
```

I know that I can upload data efficiently with `COPY` but I don't know how to handle this kind of conflicts.

Comment: `FULL JOIN` +`coalesce()`

Comment: To expand on @wildplasser's comment, you can use `COPY` to load them into multiple tables, then use SQL to select all the data into a single table. A `FULL OUTER JOIN` will get all possible `id` rows from the tables. [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) is a function that will return the first non-null argument, which is handy for getting the right value from several options.